# FeynRules vs FeynCalc (or anything else?)

Tags: packages, visualization, feyncalc

I was looking for a Mathematica package that can take Lagrangians and calculate Feynman diagrams for any given n-point function. (..like if a software can draw and calculate arbitrary loop corrections to the Fermion correlation function in a theory..)

Is FeynRules or FeynCalc capable of such?
If yes how? Which is easier to use?

If no, then are there other softwares?

Answer (score 8):

A very few Lagrangians are implemented in FeynCalc:
http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Lagrangian/
And there is a function to get Feynman Rules:
http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/FeynRule/

I have personally never used the [FeynRules](http://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/) package, but it looks quite nice
to me, and certainly is more up to date than what I coded a long time ago
in FeynCalc.

The standard for any more involved calculation in High Energy Physics seems to be FORM,
described [here](http://www.nikhef.nl/~form/).

Recently I helped writing a Link package from Mathematica to FORM, called FormLink/FeynCalcFormLink, described [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3522)  and availabe from [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/formlink/)